# Take Last Value of Duplicate Dates for Unique Symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

#Data

data = {'Symbol':['ABNB', 'ABNB', 'ABNB', 'ABNB', 'BA', 'BA', 'BA', 'BA', 'BEP', 'BEP', 'BEP', 'BEP', 'BEP'], 
        'Date':['2021-01-14', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-16', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21', '2020-02-30', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-02'],
        'Quantity':[7, 7, 6, 5, 15, 17, 18, 18, 47, 47, 48, 49, 49]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
  
# Print the output. 
df
```

Output:

```
    Symbol  Date        Quantity
0   ABNB    2021-01-14  7
1   ABNB    2021-01-15  7
2   ABNB    2021-01-15  6
3   ABNB    2021-01-16  5
4   BA      2020-03-19  15
5   BA      2020-03-20  17
6   BA      2020-03-20  18
7   BA      2020-03-21  18
8   BEP     2020-02-30  47
9   BEP     2020-10-01  47
10  BEP     2020-10-01  48
11  BEP     2020-10-01  49
12  BEP     2020-10-02  49
```

I am trying to look through each symbol to check if there are duplicate dates. If there is a duplicate, in the case of ABNB on 2021-01-15 for example, I want the last row taken (value = 6) and the previous rows dropped.

The desired output should look like this:

```
    Symbol  Date        Quantity
0   ABNB    2021-01-14  7
2   ABNB    2021-01-15  6
3   ABNB    2021-01-16  5
4   BA      2020-03-19  15
6   BA      2020-03-20  18
7   BA      2020-03-21  18
8   BEP     2020-09-30  47
11  BEP     2020-10-01  49
12  BEP     2020-10-02  49
```

It's important that the dates for symbols without duplicates remain and to keep in mind that multiple symbols may share dates.

I tried accomplishing this task with the following:

```
out = df.groupby(['Symbol'])
out = out.last().sort_index().reset_index().drop_duplicates()
```

However, it just takes the last value for each symbol and drops the rest of the rows.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Best,
Kilian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close; you just need to group by the `Date` column as well:

```
out = df.groupby(['Symbol', 'Date'])
out = out.last().sort_index().reset_index()
out
```

Output:

```
  Symbol        Date  Quantity
0   ABNB  2021-01-14         7
1   ABNB  2021-01-15         6
2   ABNB  2021-01-16         5
3     BA  2020-03-19        15
4     BA  2020-03-20        18
5     BA  2020-03-21        18
6    BEP  2020-02-30        47
7    BEP  2020-10-01        49
8    BEP  2020-10-02        49
```

Note that after using `groupby` on both `Symbol` and `Date`, you shouldn't need to use `drop_duplicates()` as `last` will have removed them.